# How to make Firebase ignore when submitting object that has some undefined values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, error-handling, undefined

This is an example of a object that I want to submit to my database:

```
item = {
  product_name: "3 Musketeers Truffle Crisp Bar",
  brands: undefined,
  ingredients_text: undefined,
  nutrients: {
    proteins_100g: 6.41,
    fat_100g: 28.8
  }
}
```

Now because this object contains some keys with undefined values my app breaks and I get error, because Firestore doesn't support undefined data type. I don't want the app to break just because there is undefined value.

I've looked for a solution and found that I can use `{ ignoreUndefinedProperties: true }`, but when I install firebase-admin with npm I get this error:

```
======== WARNING! ========

firebase-admin appears to have been installed in an unsupported environment.
This package should only be used in server-side or backend Node.js environments, and should not be used in web browsers or other client-side environments.
```

But I don't even have back end environment, can I set this rule on firebase website?

Please can someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the same as setting `{ ignoreUndefinedProperties: true }`, but firestore does support null values, so you could do this as a quick and dirty workaround:

```
var someText = undefined;

item = {
  product_name: "3 Musketeers Truffle Crisp Bar",
  brands: undefined,
  ingredients_text: someText || null,
  nutrients: {
    proteins_100g: 6.41,
    fat_100g: 28.8
  }
}
```

Basically you could add `|| null` for every value of yours that could be undefined.